How can you get ride of waswas in salah and quran and fasting and ablution?
Whenever I get waswasa of any acts of worship I want to know how to get ride of it and whenever i try to do it doesn't go away for a long time. So what is a technice to get ride of waswas as soon as i get it? Jazakumallahu khairan.

The best way is by gaining knowledge about your duties.
Since knowledge is not only power, but also the opposite of doubt as it is the source of certainty.
Note that it is agreed upon scholars that any muslim has the duty to know the fiqh of 'ibaadaat, so one is asked to gain knowledge about prayyer, fasting etc. as none is excempt from performing worship. Further any muslim must gain knowledge related to the field of his work. So if you were working in the domain of trading you should aslo gain knowledge on that.
Last, but not least to come back to my initial sentence one of the rules of thumb in fiqh is:
who ever had doubt on something, starts from what is certain.
